# Can the 5 years of aging caused by casting the wish spell be avoided or reversed?

Tags: spells, adnd-2e, aging

Casting the spell *wish* ages the caster 5 years. I know that to avoid the effects of aging the caster could acquire a new or younger body *via* possession, reincarnation, or cloning; become an undead so age is largely unimportant; or drink *potions of longevity* to stave off the effects of aging; or a variety of other workarounds. However, I want the caster of a *wish* spell to *stay* in the same body, cast *wish*, and just *not age*. Alternatively, I want an effect that actually *reverses* the caster's age while the caster remains in his original body.

Is there a way for the caster to stay in his original body and avoid or reverse the magical aging caused by a *wish* spell?

Comment: @HeyICanChan yes, extending lifespans is off-limits too. thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are several means:

### 1. There is a priest spell in the tome of magic:

> Priest 6th level: **Age Creature** (reversible)
>
> The reverse of this spell, restore youth, permanently restores age that has been lost as a result of magic [...] reduces the age of the targeted creature by one year per level of the caster. [...] A subject cannot become younger than his actual age as a result of this spell.

### 2. In the Dragon Kings Dark Sun supplement:

And it specifically states the wish spell as an example...

> Wizard 8th level: **Protection from Time** (abjuration)
>
> When confronted with a magical aging effect (such as a *wish* spell [...]), the recipient gets a saving throw versus spell to avoid the effect [...]

This one is evil to the core (can even change one's alignment), but does the job.

> Wizard 9th level: **Vampiric Youthfulness** (necromancy)
>
> Once cast, the victim ages 10 years immediately. [...] The caster becomes one year younger.

Answer (score 3):

There are several spells which can reverse the aging effects or prevent them.
**Reverse Lifeline**, the reverse form of the 8th level spell wizard spell **Accelerate Lifeline**. Quoted from *Wizard’s Spell Compendium*.

> The reverse of this spell, *reverse lifeline*, cannot bring back the
>   dead, but it can reduce the age of the recipient by up to one year per
>   level of the caster.

And the 7th level wizard spell **Younger**.

> This obscure and dangerous spell makes the recipient up to one year
>   younger per level of the caster (one year minimum), as decided by the
>   caster. It can be cast only upon a willing recipient, negating the
>   penalties of advancing age, and restoring a youthful appearance. It
>   will not make a creature younger than a young adult.

In addition to the 9th level wizard spell **Vampiric Youthfulness**, 8th level wizard spell **Protection From Time** and 6th level priest spell **Age Creature**.

If you are willing to look at items that could serve your purpose there is the **Elixir of Youth**, quoted from the *Encyclopedia Magica*

> Quaffing this rare and potent elixir reverses aging. Taking the full
>   potion at once reduces the imbiber's age by 1d4+1 years. Taking just a
>   sip first, instead of drinking it down, reduces the potency of the
>   liquid, and drinking the lower potency liquid reduces age by only 1d3
>   years.

Or the **Amulet of Perpetual Youth**

> This amulet glows with a faint, blue light. The wearer has temporary
>   immunity to the effects of both natural and magical aging; the amulet
>   grows older instead of the wearer. As the amulet ages, it gradually
>   becomes dimmer. It can absorb 5d6 years of aging, at which time its
>   light dims completely, its magic negated, and the wearer resumes
>   normal aging.

Alternatively, you could cast Wish from a scroll to avoid the aging and penalties. Quoted from page 1068 in the section “Casting Scroll Effects” in the *Encyclopedia Magica*:

> Spell components are unnecessary for a scroll reader, and no adverse
>   effects associated with casting the spell are suffered- these
>   requirements or penalties have been fulfilled or suffered by the
>   creator of the scroll.

Comment: I want to add just a important point that I use it as GM: the five year 'cost' of the Wish spell is the only permanent counter-balance of the most powerful spell of the game, taken in consideration that the only power above the spell is divine intervention, I do consider the 5 year aging reversible only by divine intervention.